# Why do I always get undefined value from other data?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I always get undefined values from other data for example: `ID:123` the response for this would be the `NetAmount: 1000.00`  after sending it using AJAX GET REQUEST, so for other data it would just return an `undefined` value.

MY AJAX

```
function viewBill(AccountNum){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "{{ route('view.billing') }}",
            data: {AccountNum:AccountNum},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function() {$('#userBill').html('Getting Information...')},
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res.NetAmount);
                $('#checkBill').css('display','block');
                $('#userBill').html('₱ '+res.NetAmount);
            },
            error: function(res) {console.log('Error');},
            complete: function() {

            }
        });
    }
```

My Controller

```
public function viewBilling(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            $viewBilling = Table1::addSelect(['PaymentStatus' => Table2::selectRaw('COUNT(*)')
            ->whereColumn('AccountNumber','Table1.AccountNumber')
            ->whereColumn('ServicePeriodEnd','Table1.ServicePeriodEnd')
            ->where('AccountNumber', $request->AccountNum)
            ])->where('AccountNumber', $request->AccountNum)
            ->orderBy('ServicePeriod','desc')
            ->first();
            return Response()->json($viewBilling);
        }
    }
```

I tried using `dd()` and it turns out there are values for the account I tried from the one that returns the `NetAmount` and from the one that returns an `undefined` value.

Comment: mybe your query return empty, you can check it using: dd, or chrome dev tools to check result of ajax

Comment: @ChinhNguyen I did check using dd(), it did have a response for both, one that displayed the NetAmount and that displayed the undefined, the one I'm confused with is why did it display an undefined value. so I checked using the dev tools from what I saw there are no properties found but when I tried accessing the route without using the button and it gives me the properties including the NetAmount.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, because of the parameter of my `viewBill()` function, I don't know why would it give me undefined values from other data I did check using the network tools, it just that it wasn't able to send the AccountNumber to the Controller. So I tried removing the parameter. I have an input tag that already has the value of the Account Number so instead of using the above code, I did this

```
function viewBill(){
var AccountNum = $('#inputAccountNum1').val();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.post({
        url: "{{ route('view.billing') }}",
        data: {AccountNum:AccountNum},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {$('#userBill').html('Getting Information...')},
        success: function(res) {
            $('#checkBill').css('display','block');
            $('#userBill').html('₱ '+res.NetAmount);
        },
        error: function(res) {console.log('Error');},
        complete: function() {

        }
    });
}
```